# Увеличивающияся картинка при наведении на нее. Почти как лупа

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Есть "хэшкодовская консткурция" всплывающего окна

```
// множество всплывающих окон с разным name. работает
// в этом диве помещаем много ссыок на окна с разным name
<div class="op_link">
<a style="{cursor:pointer;}" name="1501"><img... маленькая картинка></a>
<a style="{cursor:pointer;}" name="1502"><img... маленькая картинка></a>
..
<a style="{cursor:pointer;}" name="1700"><img... маленькая картинка></a>
</div>

// сами окошки 1501..1700
<div id="window_1501" class="window" style="display:none;">
<a style="{cursor:pointer;}" name="1501"><img... большая картинка></a>
</div>

// в конце скрипт меняющий окнам display:none;
<script>
$('.op_link a').click(function()
{
$('#window_' + $(this).attr('name')).toggle();
});
</script>
```

В интернете есть множество JQuery эффектов для картинок, когда наводишь курсор на картинку она увеличивается, раза так в 2, причем размер не изменяется, увеличение идет только внутри того места где картинка, и если водить мышкой, ко токазывается разные части картинки (что то вро де лупы). Выпилить из интернета конечно не проблема, даже сам что то придумал [ужасный пример](http://viboryou.ru/it/itt.php) (верхняя картинка увеличивается в 2 раза) . Хотел в блок поместить свой картинке эффект лупы. (Не вышло, как и с примерами из интернета).

Подскажите, как написать этот эффект лупы, что бы работал с описанными всплывающими окошками?

p.s. Если что не так спросил, прошу адекватно объяснить

Comment: Зачем писать самому, кода уже написаны десятки `Zoom` Jquery плагинов !?

Comment: Отдельно zoom есть, отдельно всплывающее окно - тоже есть. Так, что бы и лупа и zoom - чесно, не нашел. Хотя если бы нашел, думаю переделал для себя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Буквально 10 минут назад прикрутил для проекта вот этот плагин:
[Featured Image Zoomer](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/featuredzoomer.htm)

Comment: Уважаемый, это конечно классно, но при клике на фото, нет всплывающего окна (что есть самая большая загвоздка). Я помолчу про то, что там еще сам эффект увеличения не на картинке а с боку.

Comment: Значит я Вас не так понял. Попробую ещё раз: Вы хотите чтобы при наведении на небольшую картинку в её области появлялась часть той же самой картинки только большого размера, а при клике на эту область, всплывала большая картинка, скажем, с помощью fancybox'a? Так?

Comment: да. собственно по ссылке которую я указал на свой тестовый хостинг, я привел пример увеличения (нужный эффект) , вот охота такой же эффект. Ну и при клике на картинку всплывающее окно. Гуглояндексом пользоваться умею. Серьезно где то 15 страниц перекопал, т.е. более 150 ссылок в каждом. Везде глухо. Вот подобного не нашел. Увеличение + окно

Comment: Поясните, что должно быть во всплывающем окне? Исходная картинка больших размеров?

Comment: Да как обычно в этих скриптах бывает див на весь экран, полупрозрачный, и картинка в центре. Ну и клик на картинке закрывает ее (как меня научили на хэшкоде)

Comment: Я всё не могу понять почему Вас не устраивает Ваш пример, где Вы можете легко добавить к ссылке <a class="galleryitem showBlock productzoom" href="demo.jpeg" title="" ... >...</a> класс, скажем .fancybox, и по нему использовать плагин fancybox? Не забудьте только target="_blank" убрать.

Comment: В теории так и нужно сделать, на практике работает или fancybox или zoom эффект (уже пробовал до этого, и сейчас еще раз попробовал)